# The em->flush tries to insert into another table and gets errors

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 3.4. I'd have liked to use global variables so I used sessions. In the default controller

```
public function indexAction(SessionInterface $session)
{
    //Some code...
    $session->set('uoconnecte', $valeur);
    //Some code...
}
```

I set the variable and in another controller

```
public function newAction(Request $request, SessionInterface $session){}
```

I got the adequate value since a `die(dump())` of the value shows it. But when comes the `$em->flush()` I don't know why it tries to insert into another table(TypeUO) which is not the one mentionned in the `$em->persist(Place)` and by doing this gets an error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO type_u_o (codeTypeUO, libTypeUO, niveauTypeUO, typeuoliaison_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'codeTypeUO' cannot be null."

The entity I'm trying to flush (LieuRangement) has a relation with the second (UniteOrganisationnelle).

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\UniteOrganisationnelle", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uo_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
 */
private $uo;
```

This is a part of the code of the controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $session = $this->get('session');
        $uo1 = $session->get('uoconnecte');
        $lieuRangement->setUo($uo1);
        $em->persist($lieuRangement);
        //die(dump($lieuRangement->getUo()->getNomUO()));
        $em->flush();
```

But when I remove the session variables it works.
How can I solve it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is mentioned in `$em->persist` ??

Comment: I'm curious to see the result of `var_dump($uo1); die();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By transporting your `$uo1` variable through the session, the EntityManager doesn't know about it. The entity is not "managed" anymore, in Doctrine terms. Thus, the EntityManager thinks it's a new entity (even if it has a primary key field set) and attempts to insert it.

Please take a look at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/entities-in-session.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use merge instead of persist and it works.